# F# interactive in Visual Studio 2015 may ignore DLL include path

Tags: dll, f#, visual-studio-2015, fsi

I have a list of DLL load instructions that looks like this:

```
#I __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
#r @"packages\Newtonsoft.Json\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
#r @"packages\Akka\lib\net45\Akka.dll" ...
```

Note that the list references Newtonsoft.Json.dll (the version 7.0.1). But when I execute in FSI the code that uses the references DLLs Visual Studio loads Newtonsoft.Json from a different place, as shown in its log:

> Binding session to
>   'C:\Projects\Samples\fsharpreactivepatterns\packages\Akka\lib\net45\Akka.dll'...
>   Binding session to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Blend\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'...

The Newtonsoft.Json.dll doesn't even point to one of the Visual Studio 2015 folders, it references the DLL from the Visual Studio 2013 that is also installed on my machine.

Here's the workaround I've found so far:

```
#I __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
#r @"packages\Newtonsoft.Json\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
let c = Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DiscriminatedUnionConverter
#r @"packages\Akka\lib\net45\Akka.dll"
```

Now FSI loads and uses correct Newtonsoft.Json version.

Is there a better way to ensure FSI uses DLL paths specified in #r directive?

Comment: looks like a bug to me.  I would imagine that DLL paths shouldn't be affected by what objects exist in the environment.

Comment: I also suspect that this is a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that if you #I to the folder where JSON.Net lives, it might find it from there. But I agree, I've seen this behaviour as well from time to time, it's not intuitive.

Comment: Yes, using #I with the correct JSON folder solved the problem, so apparently the path in #r may be ignored (but not always ignored as we can see in the workaround).

Comment: yes, because as soon as you execute some code that utilizes a type from that assembly it forces FSI to eagerly reference the assembly. At that point with the code that's been executed, it will resolve to the one that has been referenced by #r. I agree that this is inconsistent and should probably be raised as an issue in the Visual F# repo.

Comment: Just try to do not use relative paths in `#r`, combine it with '#I' - https://sergeytihon.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/avoid-using-relative-paths-in-r-directives/